# Closet light started switching in reverse

Tags: lighting, switch

I have push button lights on several closets.  When the door closes, the button is pushed in and the light is off.  When the door is opened, the button releases and the light goes on.  Today, the light started doing the opposite - open door, light off.  When I pushed the button in, the light went on.

Comment: Did the functionality change on one closet or on multiple closets? Any possibility of a second switch somewhere (for each closet or for all closets)?

Comment: they are mechanical devices that wear out...

Comment: @dandavis Switches do wear out. But typically that will result in "always on" or "always off", not "reversed".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: it's a button though, those fail differently than household switches. I once smooshed a N.O. button and it became on normally, off when pressed, back to on when pressed firmly...

Comment: I am assuming it is one switch, I would replace it.